# Libre Office Macro to Add Picture and a Caption

Tags: vba, image, graphics, libreoffice

I need to (school task) insert multiple images in the document and also add a caption.

I already have functions that checks path, get basename and insert pic(s).

BUT I need to add the caption. If I record inserting IMG, I'll get code, that won't work for multiple pics (it keeps replacing one with others and the last inserted wins) - I suggest, It's replacing the args1 and therefore the first picture changes source path.

```
Function add_cap(path As String, title As String)
   dim document   as object
   dim dispatcher as object
   
   document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
   dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

   dim args1(3) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
   args1(0).Name = "FileName"
   args1(0).Value = path
   args1(1).Name = "FilterName"
   args1(1).Value = "<All images>"
   args1(2).Name = "AsLink"
   args1(2).Value = false
   args1(3).Name = "Style"
   args1(3).Value = "Graphics"

   dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:InsertGraphic", "", 0, args1())
end Function
```

Now, I use this function, that seems to work for multiple at least.

```
Function add_picture(filePath As String, title As String)
   doc = ThisComponent
   text = doc.CurrentSelection.getByIndex(0).End

   image = doc.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.GraphicObject")
   image.Title = title ' HTML title maybe?
   image.GraphicURL = ConvertToURL(filePath)
   image.AnchorType = com.sun.star.text.TextContentAnchorType.AS_CHARACTER
   image.Width = 2500
   image.Height = 2500

   cursor = doc.Text.createTextCursorByRange(text)
   doc.Text.insertTextContent(cursor, image, False)
end Function
```

But now, the title. I need to insert a caption with text provided via title argument. If I record adding capture, it gives me empty code.

Any advice would be appreciated :)
Thanks

---

Yes, It's Libre office Writer.

If I record macro of the process of inserting picture it gives me the same code twice. That's I believe what you mean by two steps? IMO it's just duplicit code I don't understand, can you explain?

Recording macro gave me this;

```
sub add_macro
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem define variables
dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem get access to the document
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args1(3) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "FileName"
args1(0).Value = "file://path"
args1(1).Name = "FilterName"
args1(1).Value = "<All images>"
args1(2).Name = "AsLink"
args1(2).Value = false
args1(3).Name = "Style"
args1(3).Value = "Graphics"

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:InsertGraphic", "", 0, args1())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args2(3) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args2(0).Name = "FileName"
args2(0).Value = "file://path"
args2(1).Name = "FilterName"
args2(1).Value = "<All images>"
args2(2).Name = "AsLink"
args2(2).Value = false
args2(3).Name = "Style"
args2(3).Value = "Graphics"

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:InsertGraphic", "", 0, args2())


end sub
```

Comment: Are you talking about a Writer? I could be wrong (haven't inserted images for a long time), but the process of embedding graphics in a document is a little more complicated. This is done in two steps - first you import (embedded) the image into your document. This gives the picture an internal name. Already using this name, you "draw" (insert an image) in the right place in the document. This allows the same image to be used in different places in the document without increasing the file size much.

Comment: I updated the question with Inserting image macro. IMHO both parts do the same job...
But it supports your note that the image is inserted twice. But how do I make it insert multiple image (not replace)? One solution is (IMO) to use some dynamic name when creating the PropertyValue. BUT VBA doesn't have variable variable names nor I can "destroy" the prop to make completely new one. I don't know how to solve this

Comment: Perhaps the solution that [**Andrew Pitonyak**](https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) has put in chapter [**5.9.3.3. Embed multiple images**](https://www.pitonyak.org/AndrewMacro.odt) works for you?